# Using the same column in table for partitioning and clustering in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, partitioning

I'm moving to tables partitioned by a timestamp-column with its value in milliseconds. Now I want to generate clusters by hour, which will depend on the same timestamp-column I used for partitioning.

I want to use the same column for partitioning and clustering but I'm not sure if that works to generate hourly clusters.

I was planning on adding a new column which contains only the hour related with every record, and then using this column to create my clustered table, but I want to better understand what will happen if I use the same timestamp-column that I used for partitioning.

Comment: Are you frequently querying or filtering on hour?  Just curious to see if you will get much benefit from this.  Either way, the documentation (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/clustered-tables) says `When you use clustering and partitioning together, the data can be partitioned by a date or timestamp column and then clustered on a different set of columns.`  Seems like you probably need to use a new column.

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58743050/whats-a-good-balance-to-decide-when-to-partition-a-table-in-bigquery. Now, can you give us estimates of how much data you have per hour? And what kind of queries you want to run on it?

Comment: Re: rtenha. BigQuery allows partitioning and clustering on the same column now. Thanks for pointing out the documentation. It needs to be updated.

Comment: @HuaZhang can you possibly add a few lines on how partitioning and clustering on single column can improve performance? as i understand, data is ordered within a partition based on the values of the clustering column. why cluster on the same column for which there's only 1 value in the partition? Is it in cases where we have more than just 1 clustering column?

Comment: For column-based partitioning, the column in a same partition normally has more than 1 value. For example, a table is daily partitioned on `ts` which is a timestamp column. `ts` in a partition can have different timestamps of the day. If there is enough data in the partition, the data might be divided into multiple clusters based on `ts`. A query with `ts = some_timestamp` would only scan one cluster in the partition.

Answer (score 0):

If your queries downstream do any type of ordering of the data then you could potentially benefit from clustering on the same column because partitioning can only be done down to the hour granularity in BQ.

Ie the clustering would be beneficial when you have ORDER BY, QUALIFY statement or any window function that orders on that column.

Note that clustering slows down insertion so if you don't need to order your rows down to that millisecond level you can reproduce the column and round it up to minute or hour and reference that column if you're looking to optimise your query.

All in all, depends on need and downstream queries.