# Should time partition column be set as clustered column in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am wondering that if there is any benefit or impact if the date partition column is set as the first clustered column?

I can not find any document to specify that.

I would assume that's not needed but in my test, it can be done. So what would happen if the date partition column is set as the first clustered column?

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58743051/12005425), while very helpful,  considers partitioning and clustering separately whereas OP has specifically asked about these two techniques applied together e.g. simultaneously. Therefore it would appear the question has been closed incorrectly.

Comment: @Mikhail Berlyant, my question is not about whether I should use partition or cluster. The question is what would happen if both are used on the same column.