# How many rows are required by partition to have good performances in BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, partitioning

I receive every day 100 rows from an application. Good practices in my company suggest to partition every table by day. I dont think is good to do this on the new table that I will create to daily insert a hundred of rows. I want to partition the data by year, is it good?
How many rows by partition are required for the best performances?

Answer (score 0):

It really also depends on the queries that you are going to execute on this table that is what kind of date filters are going to use and joins on what columns. Refer to below answer which will really help you to decide on this.

[Answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59318367/when-to-use-partitioning-in-bigquery)

[Answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58743050/whats-a-good-balance-to-decide-when-to-partition-a-table-in-bigquery/58743051#58743051)

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the number of partitions is limited (to 4000). Therefore partitioning is great for low cardinality. Per day, is perfect (about 11 years  -> 4000 days).

If you have higher cardinality, customer ID for example (and I hope you have more than 4000 customers!), clustering is the solution to speed up the request.

When you partition, and cluster, your data, you create small bag. Lesser the data to process (load, read, store in cache (...)) you have, faster will be your query! Of course, on only 100 rows, you won't see any differences